# Template specialization based on integer constant comparison

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Here is something I have:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t dim>
struct vector;

template <std::size_t dim>
struct vector<float, dim>
{
    // I want this implementation for dim <= 4
}

template <std::size_t dim>
struct vector<float, dim>
{
    // I want this implementation for dim > 4
}

int main() {
    vector<float, 3> v1; // should instantiate first one
    vector<float, 7> v2; // should instantiate second one
}
```

Right now, this is not a working example of course, since I can't get it to work. I don't know how to arrange the specialization template signatures. They are same template arguments right now and won't compile. Somehow, a kind of SFINAE should enter the picture I guess but I am not allowed to have default template arguments on partial specializations.

I could use `constexpr if` to handle the code selection and have one specialization instead. But I believe, having seperate specializations for these makes things more readable and manageable.

How would you achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by using SFINAE. You add an extra template parameter to the unspecialized template, then you make sure to match it in your specialization for a certain condition.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t dim, typename = void>
struct vector;

template <std::size_t dim>
struct vector<float, dim, std::enable_if_t<(dim <= 4)>>
{
    // I want this implementation for dim <= 4
};

template <std::size_t dim>
struct vector<float, dim, std::enable_if_t<(dim > 4)>>
{
    // I want this implementation for dim > 4
};

int main() {
    vector<float, 3> v1; // should instantiate first one
    vector<float, 7> v2; // should instantiate second one
}
```

`std::enable_if_t` will deduce to `void` by default if the condition passed to it is true. If not, it will not deduce to anything resulting in substitution failure leaving the way for any other template to match.

`std::enable_if_t` requires `c++14` but you can use `typename std::enable_if<condition>::type` since `c++11`.

Comment: On the first line, you mean `typename = void`, not `template = void`.

Comment: To be precise, `std::enable_if_t` is available starting from C++14.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution using additional layer. We use additional `bool` template argument and specialization for this arg. Can be used for version less than С++11.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t dim, bool moreThanFour>
struct vectorImpl;

template <std::size_t dim>
struct vectorImpl<float, dim, false>
{
   // I want this implementation for dim <= 4
};

template <std::size_t dim>
struct vectorImpl<float, dim, true>
{
   // I want this implementation for dim > 4
};

template <typename T, std::size_t dim>
struct vector : public vectorImpl < T, dim, (dim > 4) > {};

int main() {
   vector<float, 3> v1; // should instantiate first one
   vector<float, 7> v2; // should instantiate second one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With concepts you can simply write:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t dim>
struct vector;

template <std::size_t dim>
    requires (dim <= 4)
struct vector<float, dim>
{
    // I want this implementation for dim <= 4
};

template <std::size_t dim>
    requires (dim > 4)
struct vector<float, dim>
{
    // I want this implementation for dim > 4
};
```

See it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/OGeJkV)

We just have to wait for them

Comment: Can't wait for C++ 20 :P